# Find most frequent value in Python dictionary (value with maximum count)

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to write a function that returns the most frequent value in a dictionary in Python. **I do not want to import anything**, just simple code.

Any ideas? For example, if my dictionary is:

```
input_dict = {'A': 1963, 'B': 1963, 
    'C': 1964, 'D': 1964, 'E': 1964,
    'F': 1965, 'G': 1965, 'H': 1966,
    'I': 1967, 'J': 1967, 'K': 1968,
    'L': 1969 ,'M': 1969,
    'N': 1970}
```

The expected result is **1964**
*(because it is present as the value in the `dict` 3 times (maximum count))*.

This was my last attempt:

```
def most_prolific(input_dict):

    values = []
    for year in input_dict.values():
        if year in input_dict.values():
            values.append(year)


    for most in values:
        if most in values:
         return max(values.count(most))
```

Comment: Format code as code please. And what was wrong with your code?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: `for year in input_dict.values():  if year in input_dict.values():` always `true`...

Comment: Thanks, for the remarks about formatting as code. It was my first post ever ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even i suggest you don't need to import anything , its simple task :

```
input_dict = {'A': 1963, 'B': 1963,
    'C': 1964, 'D': 1964, 'E': 1964,
    'F': 1965, 'G': 1965, 'H': 1966,
    'I': 1967, 'J': 1967, 'K': 1968,
    'L': 1969 ,'M': 1969,
    'N': 1970}


track={}

for key,value in input_dict.items():
    if value not in track:
        track[value]=0
    else:
        track[value]+=1

print(max(track,key=track.get))
```

output:

```
1964
```

Comment: Given my current kwnowledge I've implemented this solution which is more in line with what is being requested. Thanks once again :)

Comment: @Martjin, yes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 11):

### Using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

Simplest way to achieve this is via using Python's builtin [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) which is created for the same purpose. Here's the sample code for your example:

```
from collections import Counter 
input_dict = {'A': 1963, 'B': 1963, 'C': 1964, 'D': 1964, 'E': 1964, 'F': 1965, 'G': 1965, 'H': 1966, 'I': 1967, 'J': 1967, 'K': 1968, 'L': 1969 ,'M': 1969, 'N': 1970}

value, count = Counter(input_dict.values()).most_common(1)[0]
# in above code, `value` will hold value `1964`  <--- one you desire
#            and `count` will hold value `3`
```

### Using intermediate dict *(with no imports)*

Here's another one **without importing any module**. Here I am creating my own counter using `dict` as:

```
my_counter_dict = {}
for v in input_dict.values():
    my_counter_dict[v] = my_counter_dict.get(v, 0)+1

# Value hold by `my_counter_dict`:
#  {1963: 2, 1964: 3, 1965: 2, 1966: 1, 1967: 2, 1968: 1, 1969: 2, 1970: 1}
```

From the above `dict`, extract the key with maximum value using [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function as:

```
>>> max(my_counter_dict.iterkeys(), key=my_counter_dict.get)
1964
```

### Without using intermediate dict *(with no imports)*

Here's another alternative without creating the intermediate dictionary, but it is relatively less efficient because of one complete iteration of the list due to the `list.count` for each element in list:

```
>>> values_list = list(input_dict.values())
>>> max(set(values_list), key=values_list.count)
1964
```

Answer (score 2):

It actually is pretty simple.
If you want a 2 line code then you can use:

```
>>> vals = list(input_dict.values())
>>> max(vals,key=vals.count)
1964
```

If you want to use a single line code then instead of putting the list in a variable use the list directly:

```
>>> max(list(input_dict.values()),key=list(input_dict.values()).count)
1964
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really insist on not importing anything. Consider this:

```
input_dict = {'A': 1963, 'B': 1963,
    'C': 1964, 'D': 1964, 'E': 1964,
    'F': 1965, 'G': 1965, 'H': 1966,
    'I': 1967, 'J': 1967, 'K': 1968,
    'L': 1969 ,'M': 1969,
    'N': 1970}

def most_prolific(input_dict):
    value_list = list(input_dict.values())

    #for each uniqute value in value_list, count the frequency, and return the max
    return max([(value_list.count(x),x) for x in set(value_list)])

print(most_prolific(input_dict)[1]) #returns 1964 in your example
```

Answer (score -1):

You can utilize the `max` function with `key` parameter:

```
input_dict = {'A': 1963, 'B': 1963, 
'C': 1964, 'D': 1964, 'E': 1964,
'F': 1965, 'G': 1965, 'H': 1966,
'I': 1967, 'J': 1967, 'K': 1968,
'L': 1969 ,'M': 1969,
'N': 1970}
max_recurrence = max(input_dict.values(), key=lambda x:input_dict.values().count(x))
```

Output:

```
1964
```